# Installing pthreads in PHP

Tags: php, pthreads

I am running the following command, to install pthreads on Linux

```
 sudo pecl install -f pthreads
```

I am getting the following error,

```
 running: phpize
 Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
 The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
 ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: `The php-devel package is required for use of this command.` Did you install that

Comment: how to install that?

Comment: When I use  sudo pecl install php-devel, i get the following error 
    No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/php"

Comment: What makes you think that's a PECL package? did you consider `sudo apt-get`, or `sudo yum install` or whatever for your distribution of linux

Comment: The php headers are going to be included as part of the development package for PHP.  The name of this package is going to differ from distro to distro, so you need to let us know what OS you are trying to install on.